# Error when downloading files from Azure Blob Storage in Azure Function: Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am getting an authentication error while trying to download files from blob storage (using library `Azure.Storage.Blobs`) in my Http Trigger Azure Function. The error message I am receiving is

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of the
> Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

I am using the `Azure.Storage.Blobs` library to interact with an Azure Storage account and retrieve blob files. However, when I execute the code, I am consistently getting this authentication error. I have verified that the connection string and account key are correct, and the storage account has the necessary permissions.

Below is my code:

BlobStroage.cs

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using System.IO.Compression;

    public class BlobStorage : IBlobStorage
    {
        
        private readonly ILogger<BlobStorage> _logger;
        private readonly BlobServiceClient _blobServiceClient;
        

        
        public BlobStorage(ILogger<BlobStorage> logger,
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _blobServiceClient = blobServiceClient;
        }
       
        
        public async Task<byte[]> GetBlobFilesAsZipAsync(string containerName, int days)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("{class} -> {method} -> Start",
                nameof(BlobStorage), nameof(BlobStorage.GetBlobFilesAsZipAsync));

            await CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName);

            var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var blobs = new List<CloudBlockBlob>();

            var resultSegment = containerClient.GetBlobsAsync().AsPages().GetAsyncEnumerator();

            while (await resultSegment.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                var blobPage = resultSegment.Current;

                foreach (var blobItem in blobPage.Values)
                {
                    var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
                    var blobProperties = await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
                    var lastModified = blobProperties.Value.LastModified.UtcDateTime;

                    //if ((DateTime.UtcNow - lastModified).TotalDays <= days)
                    //{
                    var cloudBlockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(blobClient.Uri);
                    blobs.Add(cloudBlockBlob);
                    //}
                }
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("{class} -> {method} -> End",
                nameof(BlobStorage), nameof(BlobStorage.GetBlobFilesAsZipAsync));

            return await CreateZipFile(blobs); ;
        }

        
        

        private async Task CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(string containerName)
        {
            var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            if (!await containerClient.ExistsAsync())
            {
                await containerClient.CreateAsync();
                _logger.LogInformation("Container {containerName} created if not exists.", containerName);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// CreateZipFile
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cloudBlockBlobs"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task<byte[]> CreateZipFile(IEnumerable<CloudBlockBlob> cloudBlockBlobs)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Update, true))
                {
                    foreach (var file in cloudBlockBlobs)
                    {
                        ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Name);

                        using (Stream zipEntryStream = entry.Open())
                        using (MemoryStream blobStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            await file.DownloadToStreamAsync(blobStream);
                            blobStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            await blobStream.CopyToAsync(zipEntryStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",

    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
}
}
```

Startup.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(x =>
            new BlobServiceClient(connectionString: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage")));

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBlobStorage, BlobStorage>();
```

Comment: Check if your storage account Firewall is restricting access -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/334786/azure-blob-storage-fails-to-authenticate-make-sure you do not have any firewall restrictions? And you have selected Allow Azure services to ON

Comment: @SiddheshDesai These settings for azure portal, but as I am using local storage(Azure Storage Explorer) when running my azure function on localhost, how can I set these settings for `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are mixing 2 different SDKs (`Azure.Storage.Blobs` and `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`) and when you create an instance of `CloudBlockBlob`, it does not have any authorization information with it and that's why you are getting authorization failed error.

Instead of creating a list of `CloudBlockBlob`:

```
var blobs = new List<CloudBlockBlob>();
```

simply create a collection of [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet) and then use that to download the blobs.

Your code would be something like (untested code though):

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Compression;

public class BlobStorage : IBlobStorage
{
    
    private readonly ILogger<BlobStorage> _logger;
    private readonly BlobServiceClient _blobServiceClient;
    

    
    public BlobStorage(ILogger<BlobStorage> logger,
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _blobServiceClient = blobServiceClient;
    }
    
    
    public async Task<byte[]> GetBlobFilesAsZipAsync(string containerName, int days)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("{class} -> {method} -> Start",
            nameof(BlobStorage), nameof(BlobStorage.GetBlobFilesAsZipAsync));

        await CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName);

        var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        var blobs = new List<BlobClient>();

        var resultSegment = containerClient.GetBlobsAsync().AsPages().GetAsyncEnumerator();

        while (await resultSegment.MoveNextAsync())
        {
            var blobPage = resultSegment.Current;

            foreach (var blobItem in blobPage.Values)
            {
                var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
                var blobProperties = await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
                var lastModified = blobProperties.Value.LastModified.UtcDateTime;

                //if ((DateTime.UtcNow - lastModified).TotalDays <= days)
                //{
                blobs.Add(blobClient);
                //}
            }
        }

        _logger.LogInformation("{class} -> {method} -> End",
            nameof(BlobStorage), nameof(BlobStorage.GetBlobFilesAsZipAsync));

        return await CreateZipFile(blobs); ;
    }

    
    

    private async Task CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(string containerName)
    {
        var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        if (!await containerClient.ExistsAsync())
        {
            await containerClient.CreateAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation("Container {containerName} created if not exists.", containerName);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// CreateZipFile
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cloudBlockBlobs"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<byte[]> CreateZipFile(IEnumerable<BlobClient> cloudBlockBlobs)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Update, true))
            {
                foreach (var file in cloudBlockBlobs)
                {
                    ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Name);

                    using (Stream zipEntryStream = entry.Open())
                    using (MemoryStream blobStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        await file.DownloadToAsync(blobStream);
                        blobStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        await blobStream.CopyToAsync(zipEntryStream);
                    }
                }
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only one word I can say `Thanks a lot` :)